# R - How to convert factor into ordered factor without loss of information

Tags: r

I have a factor like this one : [factor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAYlr.jpg)

This factor has 4 levels (the four possible responses for the survey) but people only reply with 2 of the 4 choices.

I want to convert in an ordered factor without loss of information, so without the loss of the unused choices. I used the "ordered" function but the new ordered factor has lost the 2 unused levels : [ordered factor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tyIV.jpg)

I would like to emphasize the fact that I had a lot of factors to convert, therefore I don't want to do this with a manual solution.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Instead of linking to a screenshot, copy paste the output of `dput(toto)` here.

Comment: use the `levels` argument: `toto = ordered(toto, levels=levels(toto))`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I obviously missed the point in the R documentation...